# MSFT/Mylar Touchpad on Lenovo Ideapad flex 5 14ARE05 Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: kernel, touchpad, lenovo, bug-reporting

The touchpad on my Laptop has never worked (since 20.04), however the issue has persisted throughout several kernel updates, now 5.11.
According to the spec sheet, the touchpad is supposed to be a "Buttonless Mylar® touchpad" but in the error messages it is called MSFT0001:00.
The note app Xournalpp can detect it although the rest of the system can't and calles it "MSFT0001:00 04F3:3140"

Many sources claim the issue has been fixed, however since it does not work in ubuntu, manjaro, fedora and openSUSE (live boots), I do not really know what to do here.
Since it didn't work in the live boots I think it should not be any false configuration on my part.

It is not visible in libinput, xinput, lshw, lsusb and lspci.
The touchpad gets claimed by the i2c_hid diver and I can't seem to be able to bind it elsewhere.

Has anyone got any idea why this is happening?

I also have a bug report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe-5.8/+bug/1912880

The outputs

`i2c_hid i2c-MSFT0001:00: supply vddl not found, using dummy regulator`

`i2c_hid i2c-MSFT0001:00: hid_descr_cmd failed`

do not appear in kernel 5.13 rc6

Answer (score 0):

try "modprobe i2c_hid_acpi". This Tip comes from the Fujitsu Laptop community. Actually my Fujitsu E 5511 Lifebook E5511MF5BMDE needs this help only for touchpad. Works fine now. Tested with Ubuntu 22.04beta and 20.04.4LTS. My older E5510 needed "modprobe i2c_hid" to do anything with input. Make it a systemd service ! Fujitsu E Laptops rock. ELAN does not always ...